# is there any way to send different badge count to different users in a same topic?

Tags: ios, node.js, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have FCM integration in my Node.js project where I am sending number of notifications to the IOS users and I need to manage notification count i.e. Badge count which will be different across the devices but I am sending notification to a particular topic to which these devices are subscribed.

my Payload is :

```
    var payload = {
            notification: {
                title: "Title...",
                body: "Notification Body...",
                sound: "customeSound.caf",
                badge : "?"
            },
            data: {
                testData: "custom data"
            }
        },
topic = "topicName";

        admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload)
            .then(function (response) {
                // See the MessagingTopicResponse reference documentation for the
                // contents of response.
                console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("Error sending message:", error);
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the devices tokens and you want to send the badge counts to respective device token,

Instead of sending them one by one ( Which I personally think is not a good idea) the best alternative you can do is:-

You can achieve this by doing something like.....
First of all you need to query your DB to get the device token and badge count respectively

So say like you have and array

```
const badgeCounts = [{
    device_token:'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
    badge_count: 1
},{
    device_token:'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb',
    badge_count: 2
},{
    device_token:'cccccccccccccccccccccc',
    badge_count: 3
},{
    device_token:'dddddddddddddddddddddd',
    badge_count: 4
}]
```

Now you can map over this array and compose array of fcm messages, something like below :-

```
const fcmMessages = [];

badgeCounts.forEach((data) => {
  fcmMessages.push({
    token: data.device_token, //device token
    apns: {
      payload: {
        aps: {
          alert: {
            title: "your title",
            body: "your body",
          },
          badge: data.badge_count, // badge
          contentAvailable: true,
        },
      },
    },
    data: {
      // any payload goes here...
    },
    notification: {
      title: "your title",
      body: "your body",
    },
  });
});

/// in firebase messiging you can do like
messaging.sendAll(fcmMessages);
```

refer doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.Messaging-1#sendall

Answer (score 4):

All devices that are subscribed to the corresponding topic will receive the same payload you set.

You'll have to send a separate payload for each device. Or if applicable, maybe just group the ones with the similar `badge` value -- but that would require you to send to a group of tokens (using `registration_ids`) instead of sending to a topic.

Comment: thanks for the reply @AL., but this is what I don't want to use and I have approached FCM. If I would group a notifications by APNS ids, I would have use native APNS system.

Comment: Hi @aatifshaikh Unfortunately, this is how it would go if you proceed with FCM.

Comment: hi AL, could you explain is it possible to send multiple badges?
I mean if I have registration_ids = [1,2,3], can I send badge [4,5,6] and it will send every badge to correspond id?

Comment: Hi @NarekSimonyan You have to handle the counting of the badges on your own app server and send different messages for each.

Comment: You mean, if I want to send notification to 10 users with different badges I need to send it 10 times, and not use registration_ids?

Comment: Yes. Handling the badges isn't FCMs responsibility on this use-case. The service itself offers the push notifications. Handling the data that comes (for this case goes) with it is for the developer.

Comment: @AL.   No need to send them differently you can use the sendAll method of FCM which takes fcm messages as an array........ I've posted small write up script as answer

Comment: @parseshyam just noticed this now because of the accepted change. Looked at your answer. So basically, what you did was make an arraylist that contains the pairing of the token and their intended badge counts, iterate through them to make an FCM message, and put the contents in the payload. Which *technically* still counts as a *different payload each*. Then just used `sendAll()` function for all the messages. I don't see anything wrong at all. I don't even see a better approach to it. I assumed anyone who has this use case would've used the same or a similar approach. Cheers!